# In Jupyter, where is '/home/jovyan'?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I don't know how to open a local file in Jupyter.Some answers say that I should change this workflow.

so, I had tried this in Jupyter on Mac:

In:

```
%pwd
```

Out:

```
'/home/jovyan'
```

In:

```
%cd /Users/apple/Desktop
```

Out:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/apple/Desktop'
/home/jovyan
```

What's wrong?
And then, I can not find '/home/jovyan' on my Mac.

Answer (score 18):

*I figured I'd answer this in case anyone has been googling for the answer.*

The folder `jovyan` does not exist on your machine. `/home/jovyan` is a workspace that exists within the docker image and is baked into it.

What you need to do is ***re-map*** the workspace so that you don't have to create a *fake* `jovyan` directory on your machine (because the docker image will be expect it if you don't specify something else).

This is how you **re-map** workspaces:
(https://medium.com/fundbox-engineering/overview-d3759e83969c)

`docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /desired/host/folder:/home/jovyan/workspace jupyter/all-spark-notebook`

In the command above, notice the two directories separated by a colon `:`

`| /desired/host/folder   | refers to the folder on host  |`
`| /home/jovyan/workspace | workspace in the docker image |`

Performing this re-map allows you to work with the image without having to worry about what it expects as a working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Well let me see if I got you question...

You can navigate using cd in the Jupyter notebook

The right way is using a valid pathway.

For example you can use:

```
cd ~/
```

It will redirect you to home folder 'Users/jovyan'

Or you can use

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

It will redirect you to Desktop folder 'Users/jovyan/Desktop'

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found it by going to this screen

[image]

which happens to be http://localhost:8888/

When I opened that, I saw all the various stuff I have on my desktop, which is where I ran the Docker command to launch this.

Then from there, I was able to import files like so `file_path = 'workspace/ratings.csv'` (the file was on my Desktop, where I launched the Jupyter environment from).

I realize this doesn't totally answer the question but I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10, for me worked a following command

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -p 4040:4040 -v C:/Users/YOUR.USERNAME/work:/home/jovyan/workspace jupyter/all-spark-notebook
```

USER.NAME has to be replaced with your window's user

as soon as u create the first file in Notebook, the new folder "work" will appear in the directory

C:/Users/YOUR.USERNAME/